# C# ignore part of string split

Tags: c#

In my C# application I concatenate form data into a string format to be passed over to a format expected by a webservice.

```
string firstName = "Test";
string lastName = "Test";
string freeText = "this is some free text, thanks";

string submitString = firstName + "," + lastName + "," + freeText;
```

Later in the application I need to pick this apart when it is returned from the webservice to be used somewhere else.

```
string[] returnData = submitString.Split(',');
```

However if free text contains a comma, the returnData variable splits it as part of the string array and I would like to keep the contents of freeText as one whole string (despite containing a comma).

Is there a quick way I can ignore the contents of that field in the string split (rather than stopping the customer entering a comma).

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs **and expected outputs for those sample inputs**.

Comment: You, probably, want to parse CSV (Comma Separated Value) and ignore commas that are within quotation marks

Answer (score 4):

If the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. there is a fixed number of "fields" in your comma-separated string (e.g. 3) and
2. only the *last one* can contain additional commas,

Then, yes, you can use [the String.Split(char[], int) overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) to specify the maximum number of items to return:

```
var s = "Test,Test,this is some free text, thanks";
var a = s.Split(new[] {','}, 3);  // return at most 3 items

Console.WriteLine(a[0]); // prints Test
Console.WriteLine(a[1]); // prints Test
Console.WriteLine(a[2]); // prints this is some free text, thanks
```

---

Otherwise, the answer is "no", because String.Split has no way to see a difference between a "field-separating comma" and a "user-entered comma". How would it know to split `Test,Test,free text, thanks,Test` as `Test/Test/free text, thanks/Test` or `Test/Test/free text/ thanks,Test`?

However, there are a few other ways to solve this problem:

- What you have is essentially a string with "comma-separated values" (CSV). If you use a professional CSV library (instead of String.Join/String.Split), values that contain commas will be quoted, and those commas will be ignored when extracting the values.
- An easier solution might be to use a different string format altogether: If you encode your values in a JSON array instead of a CSV string, the JSON library will take care of encoding/decoding values that include special characters.
- Obviously, if you can avoid encoding all values in a single string *at all* and just use an array or some other data structure instead, the problem would just disappear. However, there is not enough background in your question to know whether this is a viable option.